# how to bring up terminal when confirmation question is asked

Tags: bash, terminal

I tend to run scripts in terminal and go off to doing things on my machine. I use PROMPT_COMMAND variable to sound a bell when a script finishes. Now I would like a method to at least sound a bell or bring up the terminal when a confirmation question is asked by a script. Is this possible to do from the terminal level without modifying or injecting code into scripts? Although some scripts has command arguments to automatically answer confirmation questions, not all do and I don't always want an automatic answer. For now I have the terminal window shrunk to a comfortable size and always on top when I want this behavior.

Comment: The problem would be detecting when whatever arbitrary command you're running is waiting for input (using whatever means it chose to ask for input)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wmctrl`, e.g.

`wmctrl -a "any substring of a window title"`

Comment: That is a start. How would I be able to attach that command to when a confirmation question is asked?